# Spring Boot - All tests in a folder are excluded from coverage report

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, code-coverage

people.

I have this Spring Boot application with some services, utilities and controllers to test.
I have written tests for all of them, 35 so far, and the 35 tests get executed correctly.

The problem is that, for some reason, when I generate code coverage reports, the classes from the **service** directory appear with 0 coverage, even when their corresponding tests were executed without errors, as you can see in the image below.

For instance, the **Dummy** and  **DummyTest** classes are a copy from other two classes in a different package -**util** instead of **service**- and those from utils have no problem. The curse takes place only inside of **service**.

As an example, these are the contents of Dummy and DummyTest.

I have rewritten it without mocks, but it does not work either way:

```java
package quality.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Base64;

@Component
public final class Dummy {

    private Dummy() {
    }

    public static String encodeStringBase64(String string) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(string.getBytes());
    }

}

//---------------------------------------------------------

package quality.service;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static quality.service.Dummy.encodeStringBase64;

public class DummyTest {

    @Test
    public void testEncodeStringBase64ReturnsEmptyValue() {
        assertEquals("", encodeStringBase64(""));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEncodeStringBase64ReturnsEncodedString() {
        assertEquals("VGVzdFN0cmluZ0AwMjQ1", encodeStringBase64("TestString@0245"));
    }

}
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPUCr.png)

Comment: Have you tried to Invalidate Cache/ Restart? Do you use the standard IntelliJ coverage runner? Could you please share what you have in the [Run/Debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#services-tool-window) (in the Code Coverage tab)?

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk I managed to solve this issue for other files on the same folder by not mocking the components but their dependencies, and somehow this Dummy class -which was not being mocked, so the test was supposed to interact with a real object- was also fixed. Cannot tell you how because I did many things, it just happened. Thanks :)